# How do I allow inline images with data urls on .NET 4 without triggering request validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, url, .net-4.0, request

I'm using the jQuery jstree plugin (http://jstree.com) in a ASP.NET MVC 2 project on .NET 4 RC, and running on IIS 7.5. It comes with some stylesheets with inline images with data urls, like this:

> .tree-checkbox ul {
>   background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAgACAIAAAB4dGf///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAACAAIAAAICRF4AOw==);
>   }

Now, the url for the background image contains a colon, which .NET 4 thinks is an unsafe character, so I get this error message:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client
>   (:).

According to the documentation, I am supposed to be able to prevent this by adding

> <system.web>
>      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
>      <pages validateRequest="false"/>
>   <system.web>

to my Web.config, but that doesn't seem to help. I have tried adding it to the main Web.config for the application, as well as to a special Web.config in the /config folder, but to no avail.

Is there any way to get .NET to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS7?

IIS7 validates requests differently and you have to "revert" its behavior to ignore potentially dangerous requests.

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: I am using IIS7, but I already had set requestValidationMode to 2.0, and that didn't work either. I'll add that to the question for clarity.